# String to time in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have searched on this but my string seems to be in a different format to the examples I can find.

I have a time set as a `nvarchar(50)` and values such as `1535`

I have two of these columns and I want to compare the two to find how many minutes difference there is. How do I convert the string to a time?

Comment: I'm assuming 1535 would represent 3:35 PM, is that correct?

Comment: are your values 4 digits long anytime?

Comment: they will always be 4 digits akin to 24 hour time

Comment: `nvarchar(50)` is a bit excessive for a value that can only be 4 characters in length.

Comment: Removed my answer... I was thinking c#, not t-sql. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way;

```
declare @t1 nvarchar(4) = '1535'
declare @t2 nvarchar(4) = '1700'

select 
    datediff(minute, 
             cast(stuff(@t1, 3, 0, ':') as time),
             cast(stuff(@t2, 3, 0, ':') as time))

>>85
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your values can be convertible to `Time`:

```
DECLARE @val1 as NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @val2 as NVARCHAR(50);
SET @val1 = '1535'; SET @val2 = '1655';

SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,convert(time,LEFT(@val1,2)+':'+RIGHT(@val1, 2)+':00'), CONVERT(time,LEFT(@val2,2)+':'+RIGHT(@val2, 2)+':00'))
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: I can imagine is because you have values not suitable to be converted to time, as this: 2400

Answer (score 1):

`If you need the difference in minutes`, this is a method *`without converting`* your values `to Datetime`.

Assuming all `nvarchar values are convertible to int` *and* they are in `24h format`, *difference of* `c2-c1 in Minutes`:

**[Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3920f/20)**

```
select ((c2*1-c1*1)/100)*60 + (c2*1-c1*1)%100 inMinutes
from t
```